# selenium set profile for chrome headless python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

This is my code:

```
chrome_options = Options()
WINDOW_SIZE = "1920,1080"
path_profile = "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data"
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir="+path_profile)
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)
chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
chrome_options.headless = True
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = chrome_options,executable_path=xxxxx))
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/upload')
time.sleep(10)
driver.save_screenshot(dirname(abspath(__file__))+'/screen_shot.png')
driver.close()
```

In my profile, I have extension ads blocker and cookies login youtube
But when I screenshot,
I realize selenium has not used the profile yet. Is there a way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set `path_profile` value to the full path of your profile, add your profile name at the end, e.g. Profile 1:

```
path_profile = "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1"
```